# How to import user-defined modules (packages) properly when calling a python script through Windows Task Scheduler?

Tags: python, windows

I am using a Windows server (2012)'s Task Scheduler and Python 2.7

I am scheduling a task to be run using python. Specifically: C:\Anaconda\python.exe and calling a script as the argument located in another directory.

However, all my import statements from that script do not get imported. I tried a bare minimum script using only standard libraries and all was fine (i.e. the script worked flawlessly and ran as intended). However, when I start importing my own user-created packages (located in the same hierarchy but different folders as the script), they fail to import. I think I am misunderstanding something about how to import packages in Python.

My user defined packages are imported at the start of the script, like so:

```
import yolo

import wisconsin
```

When I run the script in Eclipse (or whatever editor I am using), the import statements work fine. This incident is isolated to running the script using Task Scheduler in Windows. Can anyone surmise what the problem may be? Do I need to be more explicit with my import statements like maybe including a path somehow? 
Let me know if something is unclear.

Could it be that when I run the script using Windows Task Scheduler, it isolates the script in its own environment, whereas if I run it in Eclipse, I have all my packages in the same environment? How would I fix this if I intend to schedule a script that relies on these packages?

Comment: Have the script log `__file__`, `sys.executable`, `sys.version`, and `sys.path` when run as a scheduled task. That should help to figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to put `imports` under `__name__` part and use it in it?
Like this:

```
...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import yolo
    import wisconsin
    # use yolo here
...
```